# Server Sent Events (SSE) StreamedResponse Blocks Requests in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, httprequest, server-sent-events

I've implemented SSE in my Laravel application. It is working fine. But, it blocks the web application for the amount of time SSE is being executed.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function() use ($request) {
        while(true) {
            $data = $this->getData($request->currency);
            if ($data->hasChanged) {
                echo 'data: ' . json_encode($data->rates) . "\n\n";
                ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
            sleep(0.5);
        }
    });
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    $response->headers->set('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
    $response->headers->set('Cach-Control', 'no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    return $response;
}
```

I have also tried `session_write_close();` but it didn't work.

Is there any solution to fix it in Laravel?

Comment: Are you using PHP FPM? If so, how many processes do you use? Sounds like a server related configuration issue more than a PHP issue...